# Infix Notation Macros In Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I want to introduce some normal mathematical expressions to Common Lisp. For example, if I call the above macro "exp":

```
(exp 2 + 3) => 5
(let ((a 2) (b 5) (c 3))
  (exp 2 + 3 * a + b - c)) => 10
```

The following is maybe difficult, therefore I do not need it:

```
(exp 2 + (mod 5 3) + (log 10))
```

Please tell me it.

Comment: There is a reason why lisp does not have operator precedence, but if you are interested there is  a [nice simple implementation for it presented by Douglas Crockford in JS](https://youtu.be/Nlqv6NtBXcA?t=20m57s) so you only have to port it. Happy hacking!

Comment: a web search might find already a few options.

Comment: Ok, I'm wrong. I'll do some web searchs before I ask it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint with cmu-afix: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/arrays.html#infix-syntax

to write stuff like:

```
#i(result[i j] += A[i k] * B[k j])
```